# Problem with "Privacy > Request > Email Data Export"

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I get the following error when trying to send data to the user.

> The security token did not match. The request was aborted to prevent any security breach. Please try again."

I don't know what it can be caused by. Admin Tools uninstalled.

Here is [a video to demonstrate](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vyjs5MNUp5wuO7CtD71gs3aZJSr2SsAx/view).

Comment: You should report this issue on the issue tracker https://issues.joomla.org/.

Comment: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/32272